# Check XML file against DTD file using expat in C

Tags: c, xml, parsing, dtd

I need to build an application the should parse an XML file using EXPAT and also check it against a DTD file. The problem is how do I do this, I checked the documentation, and couldn't find my way around.

My code so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    XML_Parser p = XML_ParserCreate(NULL);
    if (!p)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate memory for parser\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    FILE* xmlFile;
    xmlFile = fopen("test.xml", "r");
    XML_SetElementHandler(p, start, end);
    XML_SetParamEntityParsing(p, XML_PARAM_ENTITY_PARSING_ALWAYS);

    for (;;)
    {
        int done;
        int len;

        len = (int) fread(Buff, 1, BUFFSIZE, xmlFile);
        if (ferror(xmlFile))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Read error\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        done = feof(xmlFile);

        if (XML_Parse(p, Buff, len, done) == XML_STATUS_ERROR)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Parse error at line %" XML_FMT_INT_MOD "u:\n%s\n",
                    XML_GetCurrentLineNumber(p),
                    XML_ErrorString(XML_GetErrorCode(p)));
            exit(-1);
        }

        if (done)
            break;
    }
    XML_ParserFree(p);
    return 0;
}
```

I guess that the should be a call to the `XML_SetExternalEntityRefHandler` function, but I fail to understand how to use it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When did expat become a validating parser?  [Version 1.2](http://www.jclark.com/xml/expat.html) was non-validating, and I don't see any mention of validation in the change logs.  You might want to reconsider your problem definition.

Comment: In the documentation is specified that the expat parser provides some handlers that can be used in parsing DTDs. From here I think that some kind of validation can be done (am I wrong?).